# drupal 7 field collection, how to access elements from template?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-field-collection

I have a view block that takes pulls a field collection. The field collection can contain unlimited number of items, where each item has two fields (url and logo).

When I kpr(get_defined_vars) within block--views--my-view-block-block.tpl.php I get the following :

[image]

as you can see $content is just a string, so I cannot access the field collection items. I can access and template each field within field collection just fine, but what I need to do is theme each Element that contains a link and logo. Does anyone have any ideas how do accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ended up creating a view tpl and using

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use below portion of the content variable.

```
<?php print render($content['field_video_file_col']); ?>
```

Instead of "field_video_file_col" , replace the field name with your link and logo and use
    render function.

Comment: $content is a string, not an array in my case.